# How to pull all tables from DynamoDB to cross account S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a use case according to which I need to pull records daily from all of the tables present in a DynamoDB instance and store them on a cross account S3.

Essentially, it would be better to perform this pull incrementally since there could be tables in DynamoDB which are huge in volume.

I have previously done this using lambda and firehose (DynamoDB trigger lambda which then puts the data in cross-account firehose. Firehose finally puts data in S3). However, this won't scale for all tables, since, we would require to write as many lambdas as the number of tables and/or have as many firehose as many DDB tables.

Is there any other solution or single lambda+firehose can solve this usecase?

Comment: Related blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-perform-ordered-data-replication-between-applications-by-using-amazon-dynamodb-streams/

Comment: I think it's possible to use 1 lambda for multiple dynamodb streams. would that solve your problem?

Comment: @kkesley, one lambda is fine however, I want data to be put in different S3 buckets (based on tables). If data is put in one firehose by the single lambda, wouldn't it mean it would finally spit the data in single S3 bucket?

Comment: I don't know your use cases but I want to ask, why do you need firehose at all? are the data coming continuously? If not, you can just put it in S3 directly from lambda.